# How to set pointer to null when freeing a circular linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

```
 node* curr = top;
  do {
    free(curr); //free saved pointer
    curr = curr->next; //advance head to next element
  } while (curr!=top);
```

When freeing the memory of a circular linked list like above, how can you set each pointer to null as well?

Comment: What is a "pointer to null"? There are _null pointers_ and you can assign a _null pointer constant_ to a pointer. But a "pointer to null" would be a normal pointer value.

Comment: Once you've called `free(curr)`, you can't afford to dereference `curr->next`; it is no longer yours to access and may contain different information from before.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're freeing the node anyway, there's no real need to reset the pointer contained within the node.

Depending on the context in which you code appears, it might be necessary to set `top = NULL` at the end. It could be argued that it's a good practice to do this in any event.

On a somewhat related note, you have a bug in your code: `curr = curr->next` dereferences a deallocated pointer and results in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). One way to fix this is like so:

```
node* curr = top;
node* next;
do {
  next = curr->next;
  free(curr);
  curr = next;
} while (curr!=top);
```

Also note that you code doesn't correctly handle freeing an empty list. Fixing this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Agreed. Correct solution is to copy value of pointer to next before freeing the current object containing the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To make a pointer a *null* pointer *cast a constant zero* to the same data type as the pointer's data type:

```
dataType *pointer = (same dataType*) 0 ;
```